# Web page in ASP.NET and Entity Framework giving error I am struggling to resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

**EDIT: RESOLVED THIS BY DELETING AND REMAKING ENTITY DB CONNECTION**

I am creating a website that will take data from a form and store it in a database. I am using C#, ASP.NET and Entity Framework. I plan to host this website on a local server, the website/server may get restarted and I need the code to not write over any data. My web page in ASP.NET and Entity Framework giving error I am struggling to resolve. on my save db.SaveChanges(); is where the error arrives.

I used to have my ID set as a unique identifier and it would go through except it wouldn't create new lines. So I changed my primary key to ID which is an int.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using System.Data.Entity.Utilities;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;




namespace EngiData
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        EandIForm model = new EandIForm();


        string idValue = "";
        string productionValue = "";
        string machineValue = "";
        string nameValue = "";
        string workOrderNumberValue = "";
        string partNumberValue = "";
        string prefixValue = "";
        string programNumberValue = "";
        string tFileValue = "";
        string revisionValue = "";
        string programmerValue = "";
        string machineCollisionValue = "";
        string probingValue = "";
        string feedSpeedValue = "";
        string spindleDirectionvalue = "";
        string depthOfCutValue = "";
        string toolClearancesValue = "";
        string toolCallOutValue = "";
        string machineWorkOffSetValue = "";
        string programDoesntMeetPrintValue = "";
        string coolantCommandValue = "";
        string gmValue = "";
        string partTransferValue = "";
        string programImprovementValue = "";
        string otherValue = "";
        string details = "";





        EandIEntities3 myDBEntities = new EandIEntities3();


        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ste1sqlt01;Initial Catalog=EandI;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*******;Password=*******");

        //con.Open();
        //SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        //cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;

        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ste1sqlt01;Initial Catalog=EandI;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=********;Password=*************");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {







            if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "Please select a product line" + "' );", true);
            }
            else
            if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Long Sweep")
            {
                productionValue = "Long Sweep";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Fittings")
            {
                productionValue = "Fittings";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Plug Valve")
            {
                productionValue = "Plug Valve";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Pumps")
            {
                productionValue = "Pumps";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Union Connector")
            {
                productionValue = "Union Connector";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Wellhead")
            {
                productionValue = "Wellhead";
            }
            else
                if (productLineDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "Well Service Pumps")
            {
                productionValue = "Well Service Pumps";
            }

            if (machineListDropDown.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + "Please select a machine." + "' );", true);
            }
            else
            {
                model.Machine = machineListDropDown.SelectedItem.Value;
            }
            if (nameTextbox0.Text != "")
            {
                nameValue = nameTextbox0.Text;
                model.Submitter = nameValue.Trim();

            }

            if (workOrderTextbox0.Text != "")
            {
                workOrderNumberValue = workOrderTextbox0.Text;
                model.Work_Order_Number = workOrderNumberValue.Trim();

            }



            model.Production_Line = productionValue.Trim();



            //model.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

            model.Part_Number = partNumberValue.Trim();
            model.Program_Prefix = prefixValue.Trim();
            model.Program_Number = programNumberValue.Trim();
            model.TFile = tFileValue.Trim();
            model.Revision = revisionValue.Trim();
            model.Programmer = programmerValue.Trim();
            model.Machine_Collision = machineCollisionValue.Trim();
            model.Probing = probingValue.Trim();
            model.Feed_Speed = feedSpeedValue.Trim();
            model.Spindle_Direction = spindleDirectionvalue.Trim();
            model.Depth_of_Cut = depthOfCutValue.Trim();
            model.Tool_Clearance = toolClearancesValue.Trim();
            model.Tool_Call_Outs = toolCallOutValue.Trim();
            model.Machine_WorkOffSet = machineWorkOffSetValue.Trim();
            model.Program_Doesnt_Match = programDoesntMeetPrintValue.Trim();
            model.Coolant_Commands = coolantCommandValue.Trim();
            model.GM_Code = gmValue.Trim();
            model.Part_Transfer = partTransferValue.Trim();
            model.Program_Improvement = programImprovementValue.Trim();
            model.Other = otherValue.Trim();
            model.Details = details.Trim();


            using (EandIEntities3 db = new EandIEntities3())
            {
                db.EandIForms.Add(model);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            productionValue = "";
            machineValue = "";
            nameValue = "";
            workOrderNumberValue = "";
            partNumberValue = "";
            prefixValue = "";
            programNumberValue = "";
            tFileValue = "";
            revisionValue = "";
            programmerValue = "";
            machineCollisionValue = "";
            probingValue = "";
            feedSpeedValue = "";
            spindleDirectionvalue = "";
            depthOfCutValue = "";
            toolClearancesValue = "";
            toolCallOutValue = "";
            machineWorkOffSetValue = "";
            programDoesntMeetPrintValue = "";
            coolantCommandValue = "";
            gmValue = "";
            partTransferValue = "";
            programImprovementValue = "";
            otherValue = "";
            details = "";

            Response.Redirect("Submitted.aspx");



        }

        protected void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I am receiving to my

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
  Source=EntityFramework
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
       at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
       at EngiData.WebForm2.submitButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\hatchb.TP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\EngiData\EngiData\WebForm2.aspx.cs:line 191
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233087
       Message=An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       Source=EntityFramework
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
            at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
            at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
            at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
       InnerException: 
            Class=16
            ErrorCode=-2146232060
            HResult=-2146232060
            LineNumber=1
            Message=Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int
            Number=206
            Procedure=""
            Server=ste1sqlt01
            Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
            State=2
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
                 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
            InnerException:
```

In my Database all my fields are varchar(50) except ID which is an INT with identity specification.

I have a few bits of code that I commented out as I have attempted to do this through a few different methods. Is anyone able to see where the issue in my code is?

my database name is EandIForm

my connection into entity framework is called EandIEntities3

Comment: You should create primary key column with int data type with Identity configured. Identity columns will be incremented by database server. You don't need to assign values from code for identity columns.

Comment: If primary key column is of type uniqueidentifier then you need to assign values to those columns from code using Guid.NewId(). Or you can configure default value as `newid()` in database for these columns so that value for them is created by the database server.

Comment: Use the 2nd option, let SQL generate the newid() based on the column default value. Then you don't have to worry about handling failures in code.

Comment: How is the id field defined/setup in your context?

Comment: Is there a major issue with using unique identifier? It seems to work, manually in the database. I am using NewId() on the uniqueIdentifier.

Comment: I can remake the database, but I would like to figure out my main issue of how to create or insert additional rows into the database from my code, this is where my hold up is currently

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Okay I changed the ID to INT to where it increases by 1 every row. However my db.SaveChanges(); still procs an error when I submit the page

Answer (score 1):

So to answer your question around the uniqueidentifier field, you'll want to add a new guid to your model that's going into the database. You can do that with something like this, added before your `using` statement:

```
model.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Make sure you have a statement importing the "System" library as well at the top of your file, since the Guid object is part of that.

```
using System;
```

A Guid in your .NET code is just a 16-digit unique identifier, so it'll marry up real nice-like with your ID field in your database.

Some clarity on how the database will work too - a count() function won't change on server reboots, the only time that's going to change is if the data itself is purged or changed. Hopefully that wouldn't be an issue, but if you're not sure I'd ask someone at your company that may know how data cleanup works/if it happens ever and then go from there.

You shouldn't need to check for if the ID is null or empty on adding a new one like you listed - the point of a Guid is that it will 100% of the time be unique, so by virtue of adding that model.ID field as I showed above you should be able to avoid having to check for that.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi thanks, I got a bit ahead of myself in my question and forgot to ask it... How do I create a new row? What is my best bet to continue to start on a new row every time the row loads.

Comment: Okay I changed the ID to INT to where it increases by 1 every row. However my db.SaveChanges(); still procs an error when I submit the page and I am using systems